# Why Not get the selectedindex in Combo Box?

Tags: c#, windows

I selected a value from drop down in the combo box.but it always get -1 index for selectedindex property in windows form c#.net.
But in combo box Text,it has the value.it is not empty.
Here I am using Oracle database.
I want to get the selected index value of the selected row in the combo box.Can anyone give the solution.

Here are my coding for drop down list.

```
 string strLocation = "SELECT LOCATION_CODE,LOCATION_NAME FROM LOCATION ";
                               
 cmbLocation.DataSource = (SQL.getDataSet(strLocation, Conn.getCon, "LOCATION")).Tables["LOCATION"];
        cmbLocation.DisplayMember = "LOCATION_CODE";
        cmbLocation.ValueMember = "LOCATION_CODE";
```

And here is the condition

```
       if (cmbLocation.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            this.close()
        }
```

Comment: If an item is selected then you won't get -1 for `SelectedIndex`. That's it, that's all. You are doing something wrong but we can't know what because we don't know what you're doing. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Please spend a bit more time in the Help Center and do a bit more reading on what is expected of a question on this site.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a DataRow to the DataTable for text like `select`, then if `SelectedIndex` equals 0, no selection has been made.

Mock-up

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cmbLocation.DataSource = Operations.ReadFromDatabase();
        cmbLocation.DisplayMember = "Location_code";
        cmbLocation.ValueMember = "Location_Name";
        
    }

    private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbLocation.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            // no selection made
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            // selection made
        }
    }
}

public class Operations
{
    // mock-up reading data from a database table
    public static DataTable ReadFromDatabase()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add("Location_code", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Location_name", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add("A1", "Portland");
        table.Rows.Add("A2", "New York");

        AddSelect(table);

        return table;
    }
    // add row to signify a selection is required
    public static void AddSelect(DataTable table)
    {
        DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
        dr[0] = "Select";
        dr[1] = "None";
        table.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
    }
}
```